How to handle incompatible SwiftData schema versions when using iCloud syncing?
I’m building a SwiftData (& SwiftUI) app with iCloud syncing (for macOS + iOS). I have a VersionedSchema and am familiar with how to implement complex migrations using SchemaMigrationPlan if needed in the future. However, I’m not sure if there’s anything else I should do to make my app resilient to incompatibilities between app versions and schema versions.
For example, suppose I update my app from schema version 1.0.0 to 2.0.0 in the future. Now imagine a user who has the app on two devices, but it has only been updated on one of them. A few practical questions arise (there may be more I haven’t thought of):

What happens if the user opens the old app on the out-of-date device after the iCloud model has been updated to version 2.0.0 from the other device? Will the data just appear to be missing or might the app crash?
How can I implement the initial app version to handle this gracefully and inform the user of the need to upgrade?
If the device with the old version is temporarily disconnected from the internet and the user makes further changes to the local copy of the data (using schema 1.0.0), what happens when it later reconnects and tries to sync with the 2.0.0 iCloud model? Will CloudKit just not sync until the app is updated on that device, or might there be errors, crashes or confusing behaviour, and how can I handle this gracefully?

The documentation and guides I found online don’t seem to cover these questions. I’d be grateful for any practical advice or pointers to documentation I’ve missed.

Two suggestions, research the same question for Core Data since the behavior should be similar or even the same and secondly why not set up a test scenario with a new and an old version and test this yourself
